# Where are downloaded files from code saved when run as a service using systemd

Tags: c, embedded-linux, wget

I have an application which downloads a file from the s3 bucket during the over the air update. When I run the code directly from the command line, I am able to see the downloaded file within the application directory which is picked up by my code to perform a firmware update. But when I run the code as a service, I don't see the downloaded file even though the call succeeds. I am using the below-simplified code to nail down the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

const char* url = "wget https://xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xx.s3.us-east 2.amazonaws.com/firmware.bin";

int main ()
{
 system((const char*)url);
}
```

1. Running the above directly from the command line yields the below result. You can see the firmware.bin in the directory.

   ```
   debian@beaglebone:~/downloadTest$ sudo ./test 
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
   Length: 131072 (128K) [application/octet-stream]
   Saving to: ‘firmware.bin’

   firmware.bin                                         100% 
   2019-12-08 20:36:03 (6.21 KB/s) - ‘firmware.bin’ saved [131072/131072]

   debian@beaglebone:~/downloadTest$ ls -l
   total 144
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   131072 Dec  4 19:11 firmware.bin
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 debian debian   8384 Dec  8 20:12 test
   -rw-r--r-- 1 debian debian    354 Dec  8 20:00 test.c
   ```
2. Now when I run the same program as a service, I don't see the file downloaded in the directory. But when I check the status of the service, it shows the below which means the call has passed and the file was indeed downloaded, in fact, the 9th time of me trying.

   ```
   debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo systemctl status beaSmart.service 
   [sudo] password for debian: 
   ● beaSmart.service - BeaSmart Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/beaSmart.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2019-12-08 19:43:52 UTC; 59min ago
   Process: 3474 ExecStart=/home/debian/downloadTest/test (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3474 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)


   Dec 08 19:43:32 beaglebone test[3474]: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
   Dec 08 19:43:32 beaglebone test[3474]: Length: 131072 (128K) [application/octet-stream]
   Dec 08 19:43:32 beaglebone test[3474]: Saving to: ‘firmware.bin.9’
   Dec 08 19:43:41 beaglebone test[3474]:      0K .......... .......... .......... 
   .......... .......... 39% 5.33K 15s
   Dec 08 19:43:50 beaglebone test[3474]:     50K .......... .......... .......... 
   .......... .......... 78% 6.09K 5s
   Dec 08 19:43:52 beaglebone test[3474]:    100K .......... .......... ........                        
   100% 9.95K=20s
   Dec 08 19:43:52 beaglebone test[3474]: 2019-12-08 19:43:52 (6.27 KB/s) - 
   ‘firmware.bin.9’ saved [131072/131072]
   ```

Any insights on where have the file firmware.bin.9 saved?. And why isn't it being saved in the application directory?

Comment: Rolled back your edit, because answers go in the answer field, not in the question.  Editing the solution into the question itself leaves things in a very confusing state, because someone who just looks at the service file would see something that *should* work - and in fact it *does* work because it is the solution and not the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, wget downloads files in the current working directory where it is run.

A [systemd service working directory](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#WorkingDirectory=) can be set with `WorkingDirectory=` directive. From the link we can read:

> If not set, defaults to the root directory when systemd is running as a system instance and the respective user's home directory if run as user.

If your service file has the default WorkingDirectory set and is run as a system instance, the file most probably ends up in the root directory.

Comment: I added the WorkingDirectory = to the service file and it works now(updated question). I want to delete all those .bin files downloaded in the root directory. But the root directory is empty. How to know the "root of the system running the service manager"?.

Comment: Did you check the `/` directory? Or the `/root` directory?

Comment: Yes I did. ===> root@beaglebone:~# ls -l
total 0

Comment: I have updated the question with the directories I checked.

Comment: Check the `/` directory. `cd /; ls` [man hier](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html). Not "root home directory", it's "root directory".